# Refactoring a method picker class

Tags: c#

I'm working on some existing code.  After a few hours, I've boiled this problem down to a method picker class.  I find this class to be difficult to follow.  Is it possible to achieve this type of method picking functionality in a simple way?

```
public class MethodPicker
    {
        private delegate string SomeFunc(MethodPicker item);

        static readonly Dictionary<string, SomeFunc> test = new Dictionary<string, SomeFunc>();

        static MethodPicker()
        {
            test.Add("key1", Func1);
            test.Add("key2", Func2);
            test.Add("key3", Func3);
        }

        public string RunTest(string Name)
        {
            string somestring = test[Name].Invoke(this);
            return somestring;
        }

        public static string Func1(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func1 runs";
        }

        public static string Func2(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func2 runs";
        }

        public static string Func3(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func3 runs";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the class is for?  Is it just, "given a string, invoke a corresponding method?"  If so, how should that logic be dicatated -- can a mapping exist as attributes on the static methods?  Without your explaining how this class is intended to be used, I think it's going to be difficult to offer a helpful solution.

Comment: Exactly what @KirkWoll says. Apart from that, what exactly don't you understand? Is it the `delegate` or the `Invoke` (because that's basically all that is "difficult" about the class).

Comment: Use attributes on the method. Not simpler but slightly scalable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this would be a simpler solution..

```
public class MethodPicker
    {
        public string RunTest(string Name)
        {
           string somestring;
           if (Name.equals("key1") 
              return Func1(this);
           else if(Name.equals("key2") 
               return Func2(this);
           else if (Name.equals("key3") 
               return Func3(this);
           else 
              throw new Exception(name + " not found.. ");
        }

        public static string Func1(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func1 runs";
        }

        public static string Func2(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func2 runs";
        }

        public static string Func3(MethodPicker entity)
        {
            return "func3 runs";
        }
    }
```

It also highlights what is a potential problem in the dictionary solution as you have no proper error handling if the key/name does not exist in the dictionary. In your solution it would cause a NullPointerException here:

`string somestring = test[Name].Invoke(this);`

`test[Name]` would be return null...

Comment: I *suppose* replacing a general solution with an inflexible one qualifies as "simpler".

Comment: I'm not saying I recommend this solution, but it should help explain what's going on..

Answer (score 0):

I decided to hide the complexity with a new property and an extension method.

```
public class MethodPicker 
    { 
        public string Name {get;set;}
    } 

public static class Extensions
{     
        private delegate string SomeFunc(MethodPicker item); 
        static readonly Dictionary<string, SomeFunc> test = new Dictionary<string, SomeFunc>(); 

        static Extensions() 
        { 
            test.Add("key1", Func1); 
            test.Add("key2", Func2); 
            test.Add("key3", Func3); 
        } 

        public string AsSpecialString(this MethodPicker obj) 
        { 
            string somestring = test[obj.Name].Invoke(obj); 
            return somestring; 
        } 

        string Func1(MethodPicker entity) 
        { 
            return "func1 runs"; 
        } 

        static string Func2(MethodPicker entity) 
        { 
            return "func2 runs"; 
        } 

        static string Func3(MethodPicker entity) 
        { 
            return "func3 runs"; 
        } 
}
```